# Action Script: Call corresponding functions on button click

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have been trying to add buttons dynamically and then assign event listeners to them. For which my code is,

```
    var i=0;
    var step=50;
    for each (var child:XML in courseXML.footer.tray.elements())
    {           
        var thumbClip:thumb = new thumb();
        //set name 
        thumbClip.name = "mc_thumb" + (i + 1);
        trace("thumbClipname:: "+thumbClip.name);
        //set the x and y values
        thumbClip.x = 620 + (i * step);
        thumbClip.y = 560;

        //attach the newly created instance to the container
        addChild(thumbClip);
        trace("thumbClip:: "+thumbClip);

        //attach icon image from xml path
        thumbClip.thumbLoader.source = child.icon;
        trace("thumbClip.thumbLoader.source: "+thumbClip.thumbLoader.source);

        //add listeners
        trace("Node name "+ child.localName());
        if(child.localName().toLowerCase() == "feedback");
        {   trace("gotoFeedback..");
            thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoFeedback);
        }
        if(child.localName().toLowerCase() == "resources");
        {   trace("gotoResources..");
            thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoResources);
        }
        if(child.localName().toLowerCase() == "glossary");
        {   trace("gotoGlossary..");
            thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoGlossary);
        }
        if(child.localName().toLowerCase() == "discussion");
        {   trace("gotoDiscussion..");
            thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoDiscussion);
        }

        thumbClip.buttonMode = true;
        i++;
    }
```

So, Finally 4 buttons are displayed on stage and when I click on any button all the four functions `gotofeedback, gotoResources, gotoGlossary, gotoDiscussion` are called. How do I call corresponding functions on button click? Thanks!

```
The four functions are:
function gotoFeedback(e: MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("gotofeedback fn called..");
}
function gotoResources(e: MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("gotoResources fn called..");
}
function gotoGlossary(e: MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("gotoGlossary fn called..");
}
function gotoDiscussion(e: MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("gotoDiscussion fn called..");
}
```

Comment: Where are your gotoFeedback, gotoResources, etc functions defined?

Comment: You will have to show more information to diagnose this issue. As Barett pointed out, show the code for your `goto` named functions.  Also, have you done some simple debugging using trace statements? That is always the easiest way to figure out the problem if you're debugging skills are still in need of refining. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event listeners to the child buttons, rather than to thumbClip.  The way you have your code now, whenever the mouse is clicked anywhere inside thumbClip all the the listeners are called (which is what you are seeing).

Comment: It sounds like each `thumbClip` _is_ a single button, but for some reason all four `goto` functions are being executed if they are referencing stuff on the timeline that may not be setup correctly.

Comment: Good point - I rushed my reading of the code.  It might be enlightening to add tracing of the <code>target</code> and <code>currentTarget</code> for the events